# Discord.py: How do I get the User_ID of a "Bot" object?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot using discord.py 2.0.0. I want to make a slash command that returns the user id of a `Bot` object, below is a simplified version of my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
tree = client.tree
@tree.command(name="help", description="Help command")
async def help(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello, I am {str(client.id)}")

token = "My Token"
client.run(token)
```

I tried to access the bot's user id by using the `Bot.id` attribute. However, I got the following error that the attribute does not exist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trnt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 851, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\discordbot\bot.py", line 8, in help
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"Hello, I am {str(client.id)}")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trnt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 1240, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\trnt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 876, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "C:\Users\trnt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 869, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'help' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Can someone please help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation and code neither of `Bot`'s base classes, [`BotBase`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/dc4ed438a5ba780fcaaf3fb46bbc603827d87bf2/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L161) and [`Client`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/dc4ed438a5ba780fcaaf3fb46bbc603827d87bf2/discord/client.py) have an `id` attribute.

`BotBase` provides `owner_id` and `owner_ids` respectively to get the id of the owning user.

The `id` attribute can be found on the `user` attribute ([code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/dc4ed438a5ba780fcaaf3fb46bbc603827d87bf2/discord/client.py#L343)) along with the name:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Documentation](https://%20https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.application_id) for `discord.ext.commands.Bot` in version 2.0. you need to use `client.application_id` which is a property of the bot.